# Arbitrary link_to from rails helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

I'd like to create an a tag that has a base of the root path plus and arbitrary string.

I could create the string in the controller using a `ENV["ROOT_URL"]` environment variable and pass the string in but I'd rather not.

The output i'd like is

```
<a href="www.mysite.com/randomstring">Go To Link</a>

# what i've tried
link_to "Random string", root_path + "randomstring" %>
```

I've looked at the [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) documentation but it's not clear how to build an arbitrary url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A URL is for all intents just a bunch of text. Remember you must prefix any external links with `http://` or `https://` or they will be interpreted as relative paths.

In your case:

```
<a href="http://example.com/randomstring">Go To Link</a>
```

Becomes:

```
= link_to('Go To Link', 'http://example.com/randomstring')
```

Or more generically:

```
= link_to('Go To Link', 'http://example.com/' + randomstring)
```

Where `randomstring` is a variable with whatever text in it you want so long as it's valid as part of a URL.

Comment: is it possible to get the environments root url via root_path and append a string onto that?

Comment: You can pull things from `ENV` if you want, or any other place for that matter.

Comment: ok, was hoping there would be a way not to and just get it from root_path

Comment: It depends on what data you have available. Rails itself has no concept of a root path, that's something you have to configure yourself through various means. It could be via environment, or config file, or database...